# Word Problem with Lagrange Multipliers

Tags: real-analysis, lagrange-multiplier

You are building office space and have contracted to supply 10 units of space, half
at the end of year 1 and half at the end of year 2. Because large building projects are
inefficient, the cost of building $x$ units of space is $x^2$
. However, if you produce more
than 5 units in the first year, you can rent out the excess space during the second
year at 8 units of money per unit of space. It might be optimal to do something like
producing $x = 6$ in the first year, renting out 1 unit for a year, and producing only
$y = 4$ in the second year.

Write down the function of $x$ and $y$ to be minimized and the constraint, then
use a Lagrange multiplier to find the optimal amount to produce during the
first year.

I'm quite new to the idea of Lagrange multipliers, so trying out this question, I got the constraint as $x+y=10$, but I'm not sure what the function that we are trying to minimise should be. Could someone guide me as to how we can come up with that function?

Comment: Your objective function is the cost of building space $(x^2 + y^2)$ less the revenue from leasing any units built in the first year $8\lfloor x \rfloor.$  Probably, best to get rid of the floor function, solve for x and if $x$ is not an integer try rounding it up and rounding it down.

Comment: Just a small addition to the above comment, you get revenue only from excess. So the cost is $x^2+y^2-8(x-5)$